# How can i get twitter follower ids?

Tags: php, json, twitter

When click this https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=USER_NAME

It returns;

```
{"ids":[XXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXXXX,.........],"next_cursor":0,"next_cursor_str":"0","previous_cursor":0,"previous_cursor_str":"0"}
```

And How can i keep these ids into an array on PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=$USER_NAME");
$array = json_decode($data, true);
if (isset($array['ids']) && is_array($array['ids']) {
    $idsArray = $array['ids'];
    var_dump($idsArray); // that is the array you need
} else {
    die('Data format error');
}
```